# Connect to a remote sql server database

Tags: sql-server, wordpress

I am trying to access a remote SQL Server database from wordpress, but each time the connection attempt fails and I get the following error:

> ERROR 2002 - A connection attempt failed because the connected party
> did not respond properly after a certain amount of time or an
> established connection failed because the connecting host did not
> respond.Connection failed!

Although I am  sure that the instance of `SQL Server` is running on the host and accepting `TCP/IP` connections to the port and I have checked that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall.

Comment: How about the server that hosts wordpress? Does it have any blocked ports?

Comment: Hi @farah, Are you sure the remote SQL server accepts  SQL authentication for login and remote connections?